# from django to django rest framework : e-commerce with react

Tags: reactjs, django, e-commerce

i have completed an e-commerce project with pure django and want to transform it to Django Rest Framework with React,

i just want to know if the use of Sessions to create a cart would still be the same or is there something else or a different aproach to keep cart functionality,

i have been looking at some github projects to see how it can be done ,and just got me confused, if someone can clear that out for me, much much apreciated,

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I understood that it is possible to set cookies or a local storage with react and receive the info directly to the Django backend from there, so there is no need using sessions (it still totally possible but apparently not preferred)